# Where does cron find the email of a user ?

Tags: bash

When the cron daemon sends an email after doing a task, where does it find the users email, if it has not been specified in MAILTO ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about UNIX/Linux tools. Perhaps unix.stackexchange.com would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has a SMTP-Server pre-installed, where every user has a account by defalut. Also, there are other accounts like `postmaster`. To view all your accounts and their auto-forwarding, see `/etc/aliases`.

When cron wants to send a user an email, it just sends this mail to `user@localhost`. Then, you can view your mails by entering `mail` in your konsole. Also those mails are saved somewhere in `/var/mail`. After you viewed a message from that command, the mail is saved in `%HOME%/mbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you set up a mail transfer agent (mta) on you linux server (like postfix, exim etc). In the mta aliases file you can map linux users to emails.